# How can I auto get the updated data from mysql to android mobile when there is updated data from website to mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a web platform to send data to mysql DB.  I would like it if my android application could automatically get this latest data from mysqlDB.

"Is there anyway others way can be use others than refresh? [sic]"

When the new data updated to DB, I want my mobile device to be updated with latest data, too.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a real-time database.... NOT a "pull and refresh from PHP/mySQL database."

And example of a real-time database is Google Firebase:

"The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data."

Comment: Oic, may i know is phpMyadmin have this function? because currently i using 000webhost and it provide only phpMyadmin database

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not totally sure, but it is possible, it isn't easy.

Comment: okay Thanks for the suggestion ! i need take a look on firebase now

Comment: @TohKokCheng did you figure out whether phpMyadmin database would work?

Comment: @swiftlearneer nope, mysql dont have such features. You could use realtime database as mentioned.

Comment: @TohKokCheng Did you switch to firebase? Its good but its now paid version :((